# How to use Odata $batch without the EDM on .Net Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

Is there any way to use the $batch without specifying an EDM model

I am using `7.4.1 Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` nuget package, which allows me to use the $batch

Below is an example of the GetEdmModel that I would like to avoid that was explained on this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/all-in-one-with-odata-batch/):

```html
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseODataBatching();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.Select().Filter().Expand().OrderBy();
                endpoints.MapODataRoute(
                    routeName: "api",
                    routePrefix: "api",
                    model: GetEdmModel(),
                    batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler());
            });
        }
```

Comment: That nugget package allows you to use Odata without the edm approach. It has a middle ware that supercharge your rest api with the odata approach without writing too many lines of code. Check this blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/